# Will configuring AppFabric to be my ASP.NET Session State Provider also make it the provider for MVC2 TempData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, appfabric, tempdata

I am setting up AppFabric to be the Session State Provider for a website we are building in Asp.Net MVC2. Since TempData is stored in the session will doing this also make AppFabric the storage provider for TempData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The default implementation of TempData uses whatever the Session backing store happens to be.  No extra configuration is required.